# How do I emulate Internet Sharing from the command line?

Tags: macos, network, command-line, vpn, internet-sharing

I'm trying to set up my Macbook Air to share an OpenVPN connection for use while I'm on the road and don't want my iOS traffic to go over the open Internet. Sadly, Mountain Lion's Internet Sharing feature doesn't include the VPN interface in the list of shareable network interfaces, so I assume I'm going to have to emulate Internet Sharing from the command line.

I've figured out some of the moving pieces that are put in place by the InternetSharing wrapper:

- **ifconfig** to set up the bridge interface
- **ipfw** to set up forwarding of traffic
- **bootpd** to offer DHCP service to clients
- **natpmpd** to handle port forwarding
- **named** in a cache configuration to handle DNS queries

One piece I haven't figured out is the configuration of the wireless network, namely the SSID and WPA2 configuration. What service is responsible for that, and how does one activate it? It seems like it might be **airportd**, but I don't see any relevant-looking options there.

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://rodrigo.sharpcube.com/2010/06/20/using-and-sharing-a-vpn-connection-on-your-mac/) could possibly get you part of the way on your journey to the final solution, though it hasn't worked for me so far on mountain lion.  I'd very much like to know what your solution is if you find one!

Comment: +1 for starting the discussion. Hopefully some edits can flesh out what needs to be done even if we don't have the pieces documented / assembled.

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for might be slightly simpler, I have an AirPort Extreme that is currently making the ppoe connection and sharing the connection. What I would like to do is change the Mac to make the ppoe connection (no problem) and then share the connection with dhcp through the airport. Maybe getting that far first is a good start to figuring out full Internet sharing using built in interfaces, or maybe what I'm trying to do is less possible?  Also I have OS X Server available.